# Grails exclude to loading child propery or mapping?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I am working with **Grails** framework. I have added **one to many** **bidirectional** relation between `Author` and `Book` as below:

Author.groovy

```
class Author {

String firstName
String lastName

static hasMany = [books: Book]}
```

Book.groovy

```
class Book {

String title

static belongsTo = Author}
```

I want to load only `Author` class and exclude `books` loading, so is there any way to load only `Author` domain? Or how can I load only `Author` domain using GORM or `Query` ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything.  In GORM relationships are loaded lazily by default. I suggest you turn on SQL logging and take a look at the generated queries when you get data to get a good feel for what happening behind the scenes.

[Here's an example](https://spring.io/blog/2010/07/28/gorm-gotchas-part-3/) with your exact scenario.